# Mapping of jQuery functionality to YUI 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison, yui, adapter

I have a project that is using both jQuery 1.3.2 and YUI 2.6, and it has come time to pick one or the other.  I have a lot of developers that love jQuery and can't live without it, but I think some of the features of YUI 3 are a better fit for the project (e.g. the base widget).

I was trying to find a mapping of functionality between jQuery and YUI 3, and found [jQuery - YUI3 Rosetta Stone](http://carlos.bueno.org/jq-yui.html), which compared jQuery 1.4.2 to YUI 3.0.0.  I am looking at YUI 3.1.1 or the 3.2.0 preview, and wonder if there were other resources?  For a brief moment, I was tempted to write a adapter/shim layer, but think that would just confuse the issue and it is better for developers to work in one paradigm or the other.

**Update:**  I see the above content has been migrated to http://www.jsrosettastone.com/, and "The YUI team has graciously taken over the upkeep."  It now compares jQuery 1.4.2 and YUI 3.1.2

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use both perhaps? I know, I know, 2 frameworks!! All hell breaks loose! But you could still use jQuery for low level and common functionality, and YUI for widgets. There are both designed to be pretty non-polluting, and jQuery-min is tiny enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carlos's Rosetta Stone is the best resource I know of comparing the two libraries feature-for-feature.  If you find inaccuracies given the evolution of YUI since 3.0.0, Carlos does have the resource up on GitHub and welcomes updates/contributions to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused. If you don't want to rewrite your jquery code: include jquery. If you want to use only one library and that's yui: rewrite the legacy jquery code to yui.

But if you're moving from yui2 to yui3, you'll have to rewrite the yui code as well, they're different enough. I think the first thing you need to do to have think - if there are resources for a refactor, I'd avoid thinking in shims and extra layers.

The personal opinion though is yui3 is still not quite ready for primetime, despite all the cool and very elegant stuff they're doing.